# How to add bar values, set_ylim, and set_ylabel on secondary_y

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot-annotations, grouped-bar-chart

Currently have 2 problems with the following script

1. cannot add bar labels to sets 8/9
2. set 8 is "off the charts" regardless of what ylim I set.

   ```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    categories = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3',
                  'Cat4', 'Cat5']
    data_sets = {'Set1': [0.151, 0.015, 0.110,  0.204,  0.110],
                 'Set2': [0.146,    0.025,  0.088,  0.151,  0.088],
                 'Set3': [0.161,    0.027,  0.122,  0.217,  0.122],
                 'Set4': [0.145,    0.015,  0.095,  0.174,  0.095],
                 'Set5': [0.216,    0.020,  0.160,  0.300,  0.160],
                 'Set6': [0.069,    0.050,  0.069,  0.088,  0.088],
                 'Set7': [0.069,    0.050,  0.069,  0.088,  0.088],
                 'Set8': [132, 131, 139, 137, 135],
                 'Set9': [132, 131, 139, 137, 135], }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_sets, index=categories)

    ax = df.plot(kind= 'bar',secondary_y= 'Set9', rot= 0,
                  ylabel = 'test', ylim = [0, .35], grid=True )
    plt.ylabel('Check')


    for bar in ax.containers:
        ax.bar_label(bar, rotation=90)


    fig = ax.get_figure()
    ax = fig.get_axes()
    ax[1].set_ylim(0, 200)
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the right axes with `ax.right_ax` as shown in the duplicates and in [Plotting on a secondary y-axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-on-a-secondary-y-axis).

```py
import pandas as pd

categories = ['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4', 'Cat5']
data_sets =\
{'Set1': [0.151, 0.015, 0.11, 0.204, 0.11],
 'Set2': [0.146, 0.025, 0.088, 0.151, 0.088],
 'Set3': [0.161, 0.027, 0.122, 0.217, 0.122],
 'Set4': [0.145, 0.015, 0.095, 0.174, 0.095],
 'Set5': [0.216, 0.02, 0.16, 0.3, 0.16],
 'Set6': [0.069, 0.05, 0.069, 0.088, 0.088],
 'Set7': [0.069, 0.05, 0.069, 0.088, 0.088],
 'Set8': [132, 131, 139, 137, 135],
 'Set9': [132, 131, 139, 137, 135]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data_sets, index=categories)

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', secondary_y=['Set8', 'Set9'], rot=0, width=0.9,
             ylabel='test', ylim=[0, .35], grid=True, figsize=(10, 10))

ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Check')
ax.right_ax.set_ylim(0, 200)

for bar in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(bar, rotation=90, padding=3)

for bar in ax.right_ax.containers:
    ax.right_ax.bar_label(bar, rotation=90, padding=3)
```

[image]